# Optim.jl giving answer out of boundaries

Tags: optimization, julia

I'm trying to optimize a function which depends on 2 variables. These variables are population repartition, so I set boundaries to them, but when I run the code, the given answer is out of the boundaries. I am probably doing something wrong but I can't figure it out:

```
f(x) = first(myfun([x[1], x[2], 1-x[1]-x[2]])[1]) #function whose output should be optimized
lower = [0.0, 0.0] #lower bound for variables
upper = [1.0, 1.0] #upper bound for variables 
res = optimize(f, [0.25, 0.6], lower, upper, NelderMead(), Optim.Options(show_trace=true, iterations = 10))
Optim.minimizer(res)
```

To explain more clearly what is my aim. myfun is a function which simulates the spreading of a virus. So giving it a distribution of population, it'll create a graph and simulate how it spreads. So here i'm trying to get the optimal value of the distribution of population in order to get the minimum amount of infected computer. The input is the distribution of population as array and the output is the number of infected computers

Thanks you for helping !

Comment: What is `myfun` could you make a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: myfun is a function which simulates the spreading of a virus. So giving it a distribution of population, it'll create a graph and simulate how it spreads. So here i'm trying to get the optimal value of the distribution of population in order to get the minimum of infected computer. The input is the distribution of population and the output is the number of infected computers

Comment: looks like your function is stochastic and in that case most likely you should use methods for stochastic optimization

Comment: NelderMead starts by creating a simplex and I suspect one or more vertex ends up being out of your bounds. What do you know about your objective? Is it continuous, differentiable, ...